# Use a sort of Intermediate models

Tags: c#, .net, hierarchy

I am writing a program that synchronizes playlists among different streaming services, the problem is every service uses different structures and functions. 
I want to make it "modular" so i can add new services and syncronize them with the others without programming them for every service i have already in the application and the best idea i came out with is to implement it by using a sort of intermediate language (or intermediate models), e.g.

```
namespace Service1
{
    class Service1Album
    {
        public string ID { get; set; } 
        public Service1Artist Artist { get; set; }
        //Some other props...

        public IntermediateAlbum ToIntermediate()
        {
            //conversion...
        }
    }
    class Service1Artist
    {
        //Some props...
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public IntermediateArtist ToIntermediate()
        {
            //conversion...
        }
    }
}
namespace Intermediate
{
    class IntermediateArtist
    {
        //Props that every service has in common...
    }
    class IntermediateAlbum
    {
        //Props that every service has in common...
    }
}
```

In this way every service I implement accept as parameter for its functions Intermediate models and outputs his own models that can be converted.

```
Service1Album album = service1.GetAllAlbums()[0];
IntermediateAlbum intermediateAlbum = album.ToIntermediate();
service2.AddAlbum(intermediateAlbum);
service3.AddAlbum(intermediateAlbum);
```

Is there a way I can implement this more elegantly? And if so, is there a way I can inherit every service from something like a ServiceContainer that abstracts every service like this?

```
var sList = new List<ServiceContainer>{};
sList.Add(new Service1());
sList.Add(new Service2());
foreach (var service in sList)
{
    service.addAlbum(new IntermediateAlbum()
                          {
                             //properties
                          });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luca - Welcome!  You're discovering the need for some design patterns in your code.  That's really great - it means things are getting complex enough that you can start to lean on the patterns others have spent years refining in building your solution.

#### #1 - Switch to using Interfaces + Design Patterns

If I were you, I'd start by abstracting everything to interfaces (eg - you'd run your work in each Service against IAlbum's and IArtist's instead of concrete implementations).

Then, once your interfaces are in place, take a look at the .net code for the [gang-of-four patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) to figure out how to layout the work.

#### #2 - The basics

There's a lot of code to write, but the skeleton might end up looking like this

```
namespace MusicService
{
    public interface IAlbum {
        //common album properties/methods
    }
    public interface IArtist {
        //common artist properties/methods
    }
    internal abstract class AlbumBase:IAlbum {
        // implement common functions and properties if you have them...
        // otherwise, skip this
    }
    internal abstract class ArtistBase:IAlbum {
        // implement common functions and properties if you have them...
        // otherwise, skip this
    }   
}

namespace MusicService.AppleMusic 
{
    internal class Album:AlbumBase 
    {  //OR Album:IAlbum if you skipped that AlbumBase thing
        //code apple music specific stuff here ... 
        // think of this as a "mask" that the apple album is 
        // wearing so that it can pretend to be an iAlbum
    }
    internal class Artist:ArtistBase 
    {  
        //same comments apply here
    }   
}
namespace MusicService.Spotify 
{
    internal class Album:AlbumBase 
    {  
        //GO and do liekwise with Spotify
    }
    internal class Artist:ArtistBase 
    {  
        //GO and do liekwise with Spotify
    }
}
```

#### #3 - Implementing the actual SYNC

Now that you have the code you need for your various music services (neatly arranged, so your fellow programmers don't have to dig through your brain to figure out what you were thinking), you can code your SyncService.

I don't want to spoil the fun (sync service could use the [decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) or it could be a sort of [composite](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) -- not sure what your sync code needs to do), but your final sync code could be as easy as:

```
var myService = new SyncService();
myService.AddAppleMusic();
myService.AddSpotify();
myService.Sync();
```

#### Spoiling the Fun

OK.  Fine.  Here's what I'd do.

```
namespace MusicService {
    public interface IService {
        //propably a List<IAlbum> and List<IA> somewhere in here
        void Sync();
    }

    public class SyncService {
        internal List<IService> _services;

        public void AddService(IService musicService) {
            if(_services==null){_services=new List<IService>();}
            _services.Add(musicService);
        }

        public void Sync() {
            foreach(IService ms in _services) {
                ms.Sync();
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MusicService.AppleMusic {
    internal AppleSyncService:IService {
        public AppleSyncService() {
            //Do your apple-specific initializations here
        }
        public void Sync() {
            //apple-sync
        }
    }

    internal class ExtendService(){
        public static void AddAppleMusic(this SyncService syncAgent) {
           syncAgent.AddService(new AppleSyncService());
        }            
    }
}
```

Obviously - none of that code compiles, and coding in notepad is probably a bad idea.  But, it gives you a pattern-based alternative to your sample code above.  AND - if you add a third music service, you don't run the risk of breaking apple and spotify just to wedge in that new one!

Good luck.  Sounds like a fun project.